# Rich Text Formatting

Tags: android, formatting, android-edittext, text-styling

I'm trying to find a way to format EditText in an Android app that I'm planning to create.

When I created a example project to do this, all there is are plain text multiline edit text etc. There isn't really a specific EditText for rich text formatting. For instance in windows there is RichTextBox. Here thw developer can set styles such as bold,Italics underline etc. by selecting part of the text and styling it.

I'm wondering how I can achieve this in Android development.  Can someone shed some light on this, would be greatly appreciated!